# Fixing MySQL JSON array accidentally stored as string

Tags: mysql, arrays, mysql-5.7

I transfered data from one table to another using an external script. One of the columns of the table was a column called `permissions` of type json which contained an array of various permissions.

In the new table, all of the arrays have been mis-encoded as strings instead of arrays.

For instance, I see a value of `"[\"ANALYZE\", \"MANAGE\"]"` instead of `["ANALYZE", "MANAGE"]`.

Of course, any queries that try to read the column values as if they are an array are now broken.

Is there a way to fix this with a MySQL query to normalize the data to what it should be?

I tried this, but it affects no rows, and of course it also has to exactly match the order of the elements in the array on every column, which is not exact:

```
UPDATE accounts SET permissions = '["ANALYZE", "MANAGE"]' WHERE permissions = '[\\"ANALYZE\\", \\"MANAGE\\"]';
```

What's the right way to correct this mess?

Comment: _Where_ did you see the value `"[\"ANALYZE\", \"MANAGE\"]"`?  This looks like maybe the escaped double quotes are just being shown this way for presentation reasons, but they aren't really there.  Note that there is nothing wrong with storing your JSON as text in MySQL; the JSON functions should still mostly work.

Comment: It was definitely double quoted and double escaped. Broke all queries relying on that data, but I located a way to fix it by simply unquoting and unescaping.

Comment: I'm glad you found a fix, but you might want to use the [JSON data type](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json.html), which will not allow malformed JSON.

Comment: I'm using the JSON data type on that column, but some process in the PHP model converted it to a string with everything escaped before it saved it to the JSON column in the DB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed this by running this query:

```
UPDATE accounts SET permissions = JSON_UNQUOTE(permissions) WHERE permissions like '"[%';
```